# Can I use "readout" as a transitive verb?

Tags: verbs, nouns

"Readout" is often used as a noun in a context of computers and electronics. For example one can say "the readout of the image sensor is processed by the accompanying noise reduction unit."

I would like to know if I can use "readout" as a transitive word, for example, "The image sensor is readout and the output is processed by the accompanying noise reduction unit." I know some people use "readout" as a verb, but I think it is not grammatically correct.

Comment: *read out*......

Comment: it means read aloud, isn't it?

Comment: No, it means read - or perhaps read from one place, putting the result ("out") somewhere else. Similar to print out, which produces a printout. Not sure how common this usage is - probably not very.

Comment: So, do you use not "readout" or "read-out" but "read out" when you use it as a verb?

Comment: Correct - that's what I would do. Think *set up* (verb) versus *setup* (noun).

Comment: In your example here, you are not really using _readout_ as a verb. If it were a verb, derived from the noun _readout_, it would almost certainly have acquired regular conjugation, and you would have said, “The image sensor is **readouted**”. I don’t think that exists at all—at least I have never heard or say anyone say or write it. What you are writing it _read out_, conjugating the verb as _to read_ followed by the preposition _out_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use "readout" and "read-out" as nouns.

"Read out" is a special verb because it is used to indicate a connection to "readout." You should conjugate this as if it were "to read" with "out" attached at the end, e.g. "reads out."